# Change svg rate with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I found this gauge on codepen but I can't seem to find how I can adjust the values from the bubbles. The bars I can change straight in js but not with jq/js.

```
<path id="Fill-13" fill="#F8B50F" d="M3.7 88.532h26.535v-#.795H3.7z"/>
```

If you change the hashtag in a value between 0 and 12 it adjusts the gauge, but not the bubbles.

Codepen link:     https://codepen.io/sondik/pen/pdypaM/

Comment: I can not understand your problem what you want to change ?

Comment: i want to change how much the gauge displays but the bubbles stay on top

Comment: use text tag in HTML of svg for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your codepen you have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<g id="liquid">
    <path id="Fill-13" fill="#956" d="M3.7 88.532h26.535v-2.738H3.7z"/>
    <path id="Fill-14" fill="#956" d="M3.7 88.532h13.267v-2.738H3.7z"/>
</g>                                                      ^^^^^
```

I found if you change the 2.738 to 1 you can play around with the js numbers best

```
<path id="Fill-14" fill="#956" d="M3.7 88.532h13.267v-1H3.7z"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
tlBubbles.staggerTo(
    bubbles,
    0.8,
    { y: -20, ease: Power2.easeOut, scale: 0.5, autoAlpha: 0 },
    0.4
);
```

Bubbles change possition when you change the `y` value.

```
tlLiquid
    .set(liquid, { transformOrigin: "50% 100%" })
    .to(liquid, 4, { scaleY: 10, ease: Elastic.easeInOut.config(1, 0.4) });
```

With the HTML code set to 1 for each 10 in `scaleY` you get 1 "fluid level meter"